# raspberry pi zero w vs raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, pi-zero-w

I'm new at Raspberry world.

I want to make rc drone, tank, car or something like these.
should I buy pi zero w or pi 3?

I think zero w is better for mobility and low energy usage.

Also can I use zero w for web server?

Can I install it ubuntu server 16.04?

Comment: Zero is probably not a good idea for a webserver. It's quite underpowered (that's how it's so cheap). If you're not quite sure what your going to do with it, I'd recommend a RPi3, it really opens up your options in the future. Last thing you want to do is have problems because of your hardware. (Didn't have time to write up a full answer for all the questions, if it doesn't get answered soon, I'll write one w/links)

Comment: Ok I understand its not suitable for web server but for a full capacity drone like gps, rc, motors etc.. ?

Comment: I think power is going to be an issue, depending on your motors (for both zero and 3).  How are you going to supply power?   Also, what computations and tasks do you want your RPi to do?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the Pi Zero would be the best for a remote control vehicle as the brain of the project because it draws such low power, is very small and is not heavy. It has plenty of power to do any computations necessary for the task.

However, you would not use any Pi model to power the motors or high power draw components of the project. This is true for the Zero and the Pi 3. You would use a separate Motor board to control it. The Pi tells the motor board what to do based on inputs from a radio receiver module for example.

If you have no experience with development boards and coding though, I suggest as  C Malasadas did that you get a Pi 3 first to experiment with.

Then you won't have to worry about extra adapters just to get a screen working and you will get the full experience. The Zero is more geared toward embedding which is what you want, but the Pi 3 is best to start off with for beginners and prototype on.

Answer (score 1):

RPi Zero is definitely underpowered for any RC application, it's not a scalable solution for such applications. If you want to run a web server and plan to do some onboard computation or make an app to connect to with it Rpi3 would be a better option. Any its easy to setup a web server and write apps for Rpi3 by using [FlytOS](http://docs.flytbase.com/docs/FlytOS/GettingStarted/RaspiGuide.html).